# How to cancel form submit for btn-primary within form-actions of Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-next">Next</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
</div>

$("#btn-next").click(function(event) {
    $('#tab li.active').next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
});
```

When Next is pressed, form is submitted. How can I cancel it?
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/BM973/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return false` from the click handler.

```
$("#btn-next").click(function(event) {
    $('#tab li.active').next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
    return false;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BM973/7/)**

Comment: @LA_ - I hope its working fine now http://jsfiddle.net/BM973/7/. Mark it as answer

Comment: you should use event.preventDefault() and not return false;

Comment: @Mike - It is one and the same.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - return false does both preventDefault and stopPropagation, that might not be the expected result in this case...  (only valid in jquery events)

Answer (score 9):

Make it an anchor, not a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-next">Next</a>
```